# Order By Optimization

Tags: mysql

I am executing query on two big tables but when add one column for sorting (`ps`.`start_time` asc) my query dead jam and took approx 25.mins else without this column its taking 1-sec. I am sharing my sql statement:

```
SELECT  
    `ji`.`jobsId`         AS `jobsId`,
    `ji`.`fkCompanyId`    AS `fkCompanyId`,
    `ji`.`routeNumber`    AS `routeNumber`,
    `ji`.`fromStop`       AS `fromStop`,
    `ji`.`toStop`         AS `toStop`,
    `ji`.`schDeptTime`    AS `schDeptTime`,
    `ji`.`schArrTime`     AS `schArrTime`,
    `ji`.`run`            AS `run`,
    `ji`.`scheduleCode`   AS `scheduleCode`,
    `ji`.`driverDeptTime` AS `driverDeptTime`,
    `ji`.`driverArrTime`  AS `driverArrTime`,
    `ji`.`serviceType`    AS `serviceType`,
    `ji`.`days`           AS `days`,
    `ji`.`busNumber`      AS `busNumber`,
    `ji`.`hrNumber`       AS `hrNumber`,
    `ji`.`DriverName`     AS `DriverName`,
    `ps`.`start_time`     AS `start_time`,
    `ps`.`start_location` AS `start_location`,
    `ps`.`start_areas`    AS `start_areas`,
    `ps`.`passenger_scan` AS `passenger_scan`,
    `ji`.`fkCityId`       AS `fkCityId`,
    `ji`.`City`           AS `City`,
    `ji`.`date`           AS `date`
FROM (`passenger_scan` `ps`
   JOIN `jobs_import` `ji` USE INDEX(jobs_date)  
     ON ((`ji`.`busNumber` = `ps`.`busInfo`)))
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2018-d03-01' AND '2018-03-31'
ORDER BY ji.`date` DESC, ji.`City` ASC ,  ji.`routeNumber` ASC  -- ,`ps`.`start_time` asc
```

[Execution Plan without desired sorting column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRDSl.png)

[Execution Plan with desired sorting column (its problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhSZm.png)

[Indexes on both tables (all columns indexed in order by clause)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n11w8.png)

Comment: Force index is something which should not be used lightly.  Use it only if you are sure that your way is better than the query optimizer.

Comment: Please post the query plan

Comment: Pls list all indexes from both tables

Answer (score 0):

Your join fields should be indexed in order optimization Please check if `ps`.`start_time` is indexed

Comment: ps.start_time is indexed

Comment: What is the field type of ps.start_time because string type may not work

Comment: its a date column and properly indexed

Comment: It looks to me ji.date desc and ps.start_time asc contradictory

Comment: I changed into asc but still same response